# Remote Call Framework and pure virtual method somewhere

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, protocol-buffers, rcf

I'm using RCF (http://www.deltavsoft.com/RCF.html) + protobuf (https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) for remote function calling (embedded linux server + windows client).
My problem relates to the windows client.

I'm using MinGW and Qt 5.3.1 for client, but I cannot use QtCreator: it constantly fails if RCF source code is added to INCLUDEPATH. Looks like it is known problem, but not solved yet:
https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-12890?page=com.googlecode.jira-suite-utilities:transitions-summary-tabpanel

For a while, i'm using notepad++ and command line compiling. So, more to the point: RCF have two ways to perform remote calls - synchronous and asynchronous. Syncronous is OK for now. Asyncronous is OK... besides one case.

I have a lot of functions that binds to callback:

```
void p347ClientWrapper::onAsyncFunctionCompleted(RCF::Future<int> fRet, int if_code) {
     //code here is no matter
}
```

Binding, according to RCF examples:

```
RCF::Future<int> fRet;
fRet = client->anyOfMyFunctions(
    RCF::AsyncTwoway( boost::bind(&p347ClientWrapper::onAsyncFunctionCompleted, this, fRet, if_code) ), 
    any_parameter_of_my_function);
```

"client" is RcfClient

Most of functions runs OK. But one of them (looks like same as others) leads to

```
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
```

And it happens (as I suppose) somewhere near callback, because this call is processed normally on server side. I guess, this "pure virtual" is hiding somewhere in RCF classes. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way, how to investigate the case...

**UPDATE:**

Suddenly i have found a cure, but still don't fully understand the reason.

Let's look RCF definition:

```
RCF_METHOD_R1(int,doStartRotChannel_fixed,const channel_manager::RotChannelInitParams &)
```

It works fine

```
RCF_METHOD_R1(int,doStartRotChannel_orig,channel_manager::RotChannelInitParams &)
```

Causes "pure virtual method called"

So, if I declare parameter as **const** , it works. I don't know why, maybe someone could explain.

Answer (score 1):

From C++03 Section: 13.1-3

> const and volatile type-specifiers buried within a parameter type
>   specification are significant and can be used to distinguish
>   overloaded function declarations.

`const` type-specifier in your definition makes it completely another overloaded function for compiler and supposed virtual method is not implemented in this case.